# The class I made is not showing up in css

Tags: html, css

I'm making a bunch of classes for links in a navigation area and I've made for example

`<li class="main-logo">`
`<a href="/">HOME LOGO</a>`
`</li>`

and

`<a class="contacts" href="/contact.html">CONTACTS</a>`

but in my css file, when I mention .main-logo, it shows up, but when I do .contacts, css doesn't even recognize it. Why isn't it working?

```css
body {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
header {
    background: black;     
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2rem;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
}
header .main-logo a {
    background-image: url("images/ddd.png");
    background-size: 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    position: relative;
    height: 10px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 5px; 
    width: 10px;
    padding: 10;
}
section {
    background: white;
    color: gray;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
div {
    background:white;
}
/* Feature Images */
.content {
    background: white;
    color: blue;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 70px);
}
p {
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.figures {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    width: 200px;
}
figure {
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}
figcaption {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
}
figure img {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid white;
    image-resolution: 50px;
    box-shadow: lightgray 0px 0px 15px;
}

/* Navigation URLs */
/* Navbar container */
nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:black;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
/* Links inside the navbar */
nav a {
float: left;
font-size: 16px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
}

/* The dropdown container */
.dropdown {
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
}

/* Dropdown button */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
font-size: 16px; 
border: none;
outline: none;
color: white;
padding: 14px 15px;
background-color: black;
font-family: inherit; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
margin: 0; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
}

/* Add a red background color to navbar links on hover */
.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: black;
}

/* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
float: none;
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}

/* Add a grey background color to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
}
/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}

/* Footer */
.footer {
    background: black;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 12px;
    position: relative;
}

/* Links */
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    .features {
        background: cyan;
    }
}*/
```

```html
<li class="main-logo"> 
  <a href="/">HOME LOGO</a> 
</li>

<a class="contacts" href="/contact.html">CONTACTS</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fgd0rz1a/

To clarify, the issue is that I am getting a yellow underline and it says "Do not use empty rulesetscss(emptyRules)"

Comment: Please share your css.

Comment: Hello @Jon , please add CSS code of that file. So that we can check the code.

Comment: You realise that .contacts is not an `li`...does that make a difference?

Comment: <li class="contacts"> <a href="/contact.html">HOME LOGO</a> </li> ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fgd0rz1a/ @Mathyn

Comment: It doesn't look like there is any style for `contacts` in that fiddle.

Comment: @10101010 no there isn't. I didn't bother adding it because css didn't recognize ".contacts" no matter how I put it in or refreshed

Comment: Not sure what you mean by css not recognizing it. CSS just expects you define a style for an element identified by a selector. Say for example if you added `.contacts {color:red;font-size:10rem}` to your CSS, then one would expect that word "Contacts" to be red foreground and a large size. I think we may be missing something here.

Comment: @ChrisW. I wish that would work but it always gets a yellow underline and says "Do not use empty rulesetscss(emptyRules)" so it wouldn't work any ways.

Comment: Seems to work fine. https://jsfiddle.net/pf49wvb1/

Comment: @Jon if you're seeing that warning than you either have an empty selector in your css (eg; `.something { }`) or you have an un-closed class declaration or other malformed syntax. Is that your current CSS in your example **exactly** verbatim to what you're using?

Comment: @ChrisW. yes it is. Except I didn't add the .contact yet. Usually when I do it, vscode kind of tells me that it recognizes that it exists by showing it over hover but it doesn't even do that and leaves a yellow line underneath.

Comment: That sounds like a VS Code issue, not a CSS issue... Kind of pointless to ask a CSS question but not include the CSS you think you are having trouble with.